Conditional formatting formula based on value in other sheet
I use this formula in condition formatting to change the row color red based on matching value between 2 sheets in the same workbook =SUMPRODUCT(('Stop Work'!$D$8:$D$500=$C10)*('Stop Work'!$K$8:$K$500="Open"))
the formula says (if "D" in "stop work" sheet = any cell of "C" in this sheet and "K" in "stop work" sheet = "open" then color the row in red
and because this rule is repeated in many sheets in the same workbook and some cells value can be the same in other sheets so I get wrong result in other sheet that shouldn't be colored so I try to add another condition to make the formula apply in this sheet only (for example if (if "D" in "stop work" sheet = any cell of "C" in this sheet and "K" in "stop work" sheet = "open" and check if the adjacent cell "E10" in stop work sheet = ($A$1) in this sheet) then color the row
I hope I could expalined it well
thank you in advance

You need INDIRECT() on conditional formatting rule.

@Harun24hr can you add in the formula please - I don't know

In your example please tell us what range you selected to be conditionally formatted. I also think you could get a better result by ditching your weird formula and going with =IfError(VLookup($C10,'Stop Work'!$D$8:$D$500,8,true),"")="Open" as your format condition.

@ChrisMaurer it's a table range

@ChrisMaurer but your suggested edit doesnt work - however I don't understand what is meant by part ( 8,ture in the formula

Normally for VLOOKUP, The. 8 asks to return the value in the 8th column of the table. TRUE means an approximate match is allowed.

I'm not sure what @ChrisMaurer's intent is, but try changing the 8 for a 1

@cybernetic.nomad I did but nothing - I think there is something wrong or he misunderstood what I need

I tried this formula and it works ( =SUMPRODUCT(('Stop Work'!$D$8:$D$500=$C10)('Stop Work'!$K$8:$K$500="Open")('Stop Work'!$C$8:$C$500=$B$2))

Sorry, needs to be false for an Exact match.  I was careless, should be =IfError(VLookup($C10,'Stop Work'!$D$8:$K$500,8,false),"")="Open".  The 8 in the VLookup is the distance/offset from the lookup in column D to the value you want retrieved in K, 8 columns.

@ChrisMaurer  Great, it works now but still didnt cover the missing condition that I asked for which is also to check if  the adjacent cell in stop work sheet "E10"= $A$1 in the active sheet as you can see in my formula which is working now perfectly ( =SUMPRODUCT(('Stop Work'!$D$8:$D$500=$C10)('Stop Work'!$K$8:$K$500="Open")('Stop Work'!$C$8:$C$500=$B$2))  but i changed $A$1 to be $B$2 ---- thanks for your help anyway

I have tried this formula and it works
=SUMPRODUCT(('Stop Work'!$D$8:$D$500=$C10)('Stop Work'!$K$8:$K$500="Open")('Stop Work'!$C$8:$C$500=$B$2))
thank you anyway
